# Форма на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пускай есть формочка на странице, нужно командами Javascript и jQuery (консоль) заставить скрипт вставлять число 1 в эту форму и отправлять, то есть суть скрипта:

1. вставить в форму число 1,
2. нажать на кнопку.

Comment: Javascript и jQuery это разные языки если - **И**? Для начала научитесь доносить корректно вопрос людям а не ботам ПС!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form>
    <input />
</form>
```

...

```
$('form').find('input').val(1).end().submit();
```

[**Пример.**](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbay/RKqR5/)